# Tkinter callback KeyError in Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, keyerror

I am trying to write code that will make it easier for my colleagues to follow several aspects of our IT policies. Part of the code will deal with backing up files.

I have code that enables people add (source) files and (destination) folders. These are saved in a file called backups.csv. For testing purposes I have populated it with these lines:

C:/Users/zorin/Downloads/OpenShot-v3.1.1-x86_64.exe,C:/Users/zorin/Documents

C:/Users/zorin/Downloads/SyncBack_Setup.exe,C:/Users/zorin/Documents

C:/Users/zorin/Downloads/Perspective.epub,C:/Users/zorin/Documents/Becky.

This part of the code works fine.

Next I want these entries to show in a Tkinter listbox so I can select multiple files (and destination folders). This is the code I have:

```
import tkinter as tk
import csv
import os

def flash():
    entry1.delete(0,"end")
    stuff = listbox1.curselection()
    entry1.insert(0,items[stuff[0]])
    
root =tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x500")

listbox1=tk.Listbox(root,width=100,selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
with open("backups.csv",mode="r",newline='') as c:
    reader = csv.reader(c)
    items = dict(reader)

for x,y in enumerate(items):
    listbox1.insert(x+1,y)
listbox1.pack(anchor="w")

label1 = tk.Label(root, text="").pack()
entry1 = tk.Entry(root,width=50)
entry1.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(root,text="Select",command=flash)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I run the code the first column of the csv file shows in the listbox. However, when I select an entry and click the 'select' button I get a KeyError:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\zorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1921, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "F:\2 Software\Alex\dadpart3.py", line 42, in flash
entry1.insert(0,items[stuff[0]])
KeyError:

Any suggestions what causes the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you examined `items` and `stuff` to verify they contains what you assume they contain? Also, this example would be better if you added some hard-coded data instead of relying on an external csv file. I don't think the problem is dependent on where the data comes from.,

Comment: Thanks. The listbox shows the right options, so 'items' works OK. I told the code to print 'stuff' and it is either 0, 1 or 2 (depending on whether I click the 1st, 2nd or 3rd entry in the listbox). That number also appears in last line of the error message (if I click the 1st entry the error message ends with "KeyError: 0", etc.).     The files and destination paths will be different for each user, so they cannot be hard coded.

Comment: They can be  hard-coded _for this example_.

Comment: Also, you should separate `entry1.,insert(0, items[stuff[0]])` into two lines so you can tell if it's complaining about `stuff[0]` or `items[stuff[0]]`. You absolutely cannot get that error if `stuff` is non-empty, and if the value it contains is in fact a correct key for `items`. Make sure that `stuff[0]` is also the correct type. For example, it could be the string `"0"`, but the keys in `items` might be integers, or visa versa.

Comment: `items` is a dictionary, so the key should be the text of the selected item, not the index.

Answer (score 0):

Since `items` is a dictionary, you need to use the text of the selected items in the listbox as the key, not the selected indexes:

```py
def flash():
    entry1.delete(0, "end")
    stuff = listbox1.curselection()
    # get all the text of selected items (as multiple selections is enabled)
    keys = [listbox1.get(x) for x in stuff] 
    # get the corresponding items and join them into a single string
    selected = ', '.join(items[x] for x in keys)
    entry1.insert(0, selected)
```